# Similarity between two samples

Tags: statistics

Imagine a repository of a really large number of items. Each item in this sample (and in the repository) belongs to a category. Each items belongs to a single category. I take a sample from it.

For exemple, if I take 5 items, one is a hammer, two are shovels and other one is a a nail.

I belive - maybe incorrectly - from the central value theorem, for a sufficiently large number of samples, the quantities (%) of items on each category are going to be always approximate between samples taken from the same repository of items.

I'd like to take a sample from another repository and from the distribution of items on each category, measure in some way a degree of similarity between the two repositories, ie. if the two repositories have the same distribution of itens on each category.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you mean the central limit theorem? There is no need to use it, the experiment you describe follows a known distribution, a multivariate generalization of the hypergeometric distribution. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution